# Recursion of internal functions in Erlang

Tags: recursion, erlang

Playing with Erlang, I've got a process-looping function like:

```
process_loop(...A long list of parameters here...) ->
    receive
        ...Message processing logic involving the function parameters...
    end,
    process_loop(...Same long list of parameters...)
end.
```

It looks quite ugly, so I tried a refactoring like that:

```
process_loop(...A long list of parameters...) ->
    Loop = fun() ->
        receive
            ...Message processing logic...
        end,
        Loop()
    end,
    Loop()
end.
```

But it turned out to be incorrect, as Loop variable is unbound inside the Loop function. So, I've arranged a workaround:

```
process_loop(...A long list of parameters...) ->
    Loop = fun(Next) ->
        receive
            ...Message processing logic...
        end,
        Next(Next)
    end,
    Loop(Loop)
end.
```

I have two questions:

1. Is there a way to achieve the idea of snippet #2, but without such "Next(Next)" workarounds?
2. Do snippets #1 and #3 differ significantly in terms of performance, or they're equivalent?

Comment: I put this here because it doesn't answer your question per se: I recommend that you keep the way you did in the first snippet and move the recursion (the call to the process_loop function) after each clause. This has a number of benefits: 1) Enables you to do hot code-reload which is more tricky with funs. 2) It is cleaner and more readable. 3) It is traceable. Fun-recursion isn't as fun as it sounds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. No. Unfortunately anonymous function are just that. Anonymous, unless you give them a name.
2. Snippet #3 is a little bit more expensive. Given that you do pattern matching on messages in the body, I wouldn't worry about it. Optimise for readability in this case. The difference is a very small constant factor.

Answer (score 2):

1. You might use tuples/records as named parameters instead of passing lots of parameters. You can just reuse the single parameter that the function is going to take.
2. I guess (but I' not sure) that this syntax isn't supported by proper tail-recursion. If you refactor to use a single parameter I think that you will be again on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

The more conventional way of avoiding repeating the list of parameters in snippet #1 is to put all or most of them in a record that holds the loop state. Then you only have one or a few variables to pass around in the loop. That's easier to read and harder to screw up than playing around with recursive funs.

Answer (score 0):

I must say that in all cases where I do this type of recursion I don't think I have ever come across the case where exactly the **same** set of variables is passed around in the recursion. Usually variables will change reflecting state change in the process loop. It cannot be otherwise as you have to handle state explicitly. I usually group related parameters into records which cuts down the number of arguments and adds clarity.

You can of course use your solution and have some parameters implicit in the fun and some explicit in the recursive calls but I don't think this would improve clarity.

The same answer applies to "normal" recursion where you are stepping over data structures.